# Can a build system be version control aware?

Tags: git, makefile, version-control, msbuild, build-system

Make, ant, msbuild, ... all the build tools I know of compare artefact *timestamps* to decide the need for rebuilding.

Git resets source file timestamp to 'now' when checking out any version in order to tell the build system: artefacts depending on these files should be rebuilt.

However:

```
$ git checkout old_version # retrieving a.cpp@old_version
$ make # building a.out from a.cpp
$ git checkout new_version # updating a.cpp@new_version
$ git checkout - # resetting a.cpp@old_version
$ make # ...
```

could be equivalent to a no-op if only make could determine that `a.out` has been built with old_version.

Is there a way to achive this?  Do you know of any build system/version control system that can cooperate in this way?

Comment: Maybe a `post-checkout` hook can help.

Answer (score 1):

Exclusive reliance on timestamps is in fact a deficiency of those build systems. It fails for example in the following cases:

1. You want to rebuild with a different set of compiler flags.
2. Sources and build artifacts reside on different filesystems with desynchronized clocks.
3. Timestamps are tweaked in order to optimize the build process (just like in your case) but it is done in an way that results in an inconsistent view of the sources (i.e. not everything that had to be rebuilt is actually rebuilt).

> Make, ant, msbuild, ... all the build tools I know of compare artefact
>   timestamps to decide the need for rebuilding.

Look at [scons](http://scons.org). One of its notable differences from other build tools is the *Reliable detection of build changes using MD5 signatures*. This means that it stores for each target the MD5 hashes of sources and the command line that were used for building that target. Before rebuilding a target, it re-computes the MD5 hashes and knows if the recompilation is required. Of course it is slower than merely looking at the timestamps but devoid of the mentioned problems. However, scons also provides *optional, configurable support for traditional timestamps*.